# See all objects in some running JVM

Tags: java, object, jvm, heap-memory

I have a large distributed application with 20,000+ objects. I would like to be able to connect to this running JVM externally and view any arbitrary object and its attributes at any time.

For example, if I have some object instance from the following class

```
class Temp {
    int attribute = 0;
    String name = "John";
}
```

I would like to be able to connect to the JVM and see all instances of this class and its `attribute` and `name` values.

I believe this would be possible with a heap dump, but this would be extremely expensive given the application. Also, analyzing such a heap dump is extremely challenging when the size is in the 1GB+ range. Is there some other utility that can provide a triggered snapshot of all objects? Or perhaps a more clever solution to my problem?

I've looked into [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) and the [Java Flight Recorder](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15070/quickstart.htm) but these do not provide the features I need. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to analyze the state of specific objects or any arbitrary object? Because for example the Eclipse debugger can help you. If not the JVM Monitor is a rather capable tool which is an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @AdamArold I'm interested in specific objects. Primarily the `HttpSession` at arbitrary times.

Comment: Did you try debugging your project?

Comment: Attaching a remote debugger is a possibility in this case, but it's a fall back. I still am curious if there is a solution to the above requirement. This seems like something that should have some 3rd party solution. Using OQL on a heap dump with MAT is another possibility, but again: flexibility is key. Being able to trigger the snapshot whenever I want is my big concern